# How to calculate the decomposition A=P[I_r,0;0,0]Q in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, equivalence

Given matrix A, is it possible to conveniently get the invertible matrices P and Q that appear in the [matrix equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence) and satisfy A=P[I_r,0;0,0]Q with numpy or scipy?

Comment: Do you know to calculate the decomposition without python? If yes [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html) should give you the needed tools, to implement that in python.

Comment: And what do you mean by [I_r,0;0,0]?

Comment: @Dschoni It's a block matrix, which is almost an identity matrix but with only `r` 1's

Comment: @Dschoni I can do it as the manual way but I wonder whether there are built-in methods. This it important for calculating all generalized matrix inverses.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can do a singular value decomposition (SVD) and then multiply the singular values to one of the unitary matrice.

See definition of SVD at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

basically you will get a unitary matrix, a diagonal matrix and another unitary matrix. The diagonal matrix has number of nonzero elements equal to rank(A).

In python code, it's

```
P, S, Q = numpy.linalg.svd(A)
for i, row in enumerate(Q):
  row *= S[i]
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html about numpy.linalg.svd

P, Q then become exactly what you want. But keep in mind there's not a unique way of such decomposition.

Comment: Right. I solved this via LU decomposition but I think this is better.